# Installation/use of dask.array on python3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-3.4, dask

I'm testing the dask module (https://github.com/ContinuumIO/dask) to work with big data arrays, but couldn't make it work so far. At a first glance, it seems to me that there's a conflict with some reserved name or something similar.

The installation was made with $pip3 install dask on ubuntu, tested on IPython 1.2.1 with Python 3.4.0.

I attach a minimum non-working example.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: import dask.array as da
In [3]: x=da.random.normal(10,0.1,size=(10000,10000),chunks=(1000,1000))
In [4]: type(x)
Out[4]: toolz.functoolz.curry
In [5]: x.dask
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-7982e592385b> in <module>()
----> 1 x.dask

AttributeError: 'curry' object has no attribute 'dask'
```

Comment: Are you using the latest released version?  How about master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: import dask.array as da
In [3]: x = da.random.normal(10, 0.1, size=(10000, 10000), chunks=(1000, 1000))
In [4]: type(x)
Out[4]: dask.array.core.Array

In [5]: import dask
In [6]: dask.__version__
Out[6]: '0.6.0'
```

Comment: Still not working. I tried it on 2 computers, the one with IPython 3.4.0 shows the errors in the question.
The second one, with IPython 3.4.3 doesn't even let import dask.array at all...

Comment: You need to upgrade dask, not Python or IPython

Comment: It works! 
    pip3 install --upgrade "dask[complete]" ←did the trick!
Thanks! :)